# How to create many-to-one relation with django and to display it in admin interface

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have the following problem - I would like to create many-to-one mapping in django to represent what is basically relation between object and pieces of object like:

```
class Website(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

class WebsiteIp(models.Model):
    website = models.ForeignKey(Website, primary_key = True)
    ip = models.CharField(max_length = 40, primary_key = True)
    introduction_date = models.DateField()
```

which should all be presented on website (parent object) editing page. Although it sounds like trivial problem I couldn't really find anything useful on this

Answer (score 3):

Add the related_name parameter to your ForeignKey on WebsiteIP like so:

```
class Website(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

class WebsiteIp(models.Model):
    website = models.ForeignKey(Website, primary_key = True, related_name="IPs")
    ip = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    introduction_date = models.DateField()
```

Then, you can reference the IPs as a many-to-one mapping from Website like so:

```
website = Website.objects.filter(name="blah")
if website.count():
  IPs = website[0].IPs
```

Untested of course, but this should get you in the right direction.  Also check out: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#many-to-one-relationships

In your admin.py, where you presumably have something like this:

```
class WebsiteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ('name',)
  search_fields = ['name']
  ordering = ('name', )
```

Update to the following:

```
class WebsiteIpInline(admin.TabularInline):
  model = WebsiteIp
  extra = 1

class WebsiteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ('name',)
  search_fields = ['name']
  inlines = ( WebsiteIpInline, )
  ordering = ('name', )
```

Should display what you want!

Comment: I understand related_name would create member with that name on foreign key target object, but I don't understand how I could use that to get ability to add/delete/modify ip on website editing page in django admin?

Comment: It does display place for one websiteip and if I enter something there then I can edit that, but I can't add multiple ips (I assume that extra=1 should mean "always create form for one extra object to enter"?)

Comment: You should be able to press a `+` symbol to create more add forms for the IP, alternatively, you can set extra = n where n is a larger number.

Comment: It shows only single empty input before I fill it with IP, and after that it allows only editing of that entered value (no additional inputs, no + link), I suspect it is database structure that is confusing django (second table has composite primary key (website_id, ip)), and I can't let django manage table structure because it is existing database used by other applications (I just want to administer data in it using django).

Comment: Have you tried setting `extra = 5`, for example?  Also, do you see the `+` symbol?  I do this all the time and I do not have any trouble with it.  In fact, sometimes I wish to turn off the ability to add new entries.  You can do this by setting 'max_num = 0', make sure you don't have that in your inline definition.

Comment: Are you certain that your database is in sync with your model?  You should manually check that your MySQL scheme reflects your models.  I've seen issues with this in the past, and they will often show up as weirdness in the Admin display.

Comment: Well, whatever your new issue is, wouldn't you agree I've addressed your original question accurately?

Comment: You did address it well, but proposed solution is not working - seems django is not able to support composite primary keys yet (I found some mentioning of patch for that, but it seems outdated), so I am giving up on django and checking if sqlalchemy+pyramid is better suited for my specific needs

Comment: Ok, sounds great. In the mean-time, how about accepting my answer?

Comment: Your answer is not solution for this problem

Comment: My answer is absolutely THE answer to the question you posted. You appear to be having new issues that you did not state in your question. Thank you for wasting my time.

Comment: For anyone else reading along, the OP added the compound primary key to his question long after I answered his original question.

Answer (score 0):

Work around this problem is to modify primary key settings on dependant relation (but that works only in cases like this - when there is one piece of key that might be unique for entire table (ip in this case)).

```
class WebsiteIp(models.Model):
    website = models.ForeignKey(Website)
    ip = models.CharField(max_length = 40, primary_key = True)
    introduction_date = models.DateField()
```

After this (and only after this), part of solution proposed by mkoistinen would work in expected way. General problem is that django is checking ability to create new objects by examining uniqueness of primary key columns (in a wrong way), so I guess it is possible to fix that too by overriding some of models.Model methods, but I don't know enough about django internals to be able to point what method.