# Django: Simple One:Many fields aren't showing in parent object view in admin

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and have made a couple of classes whereby one Account can have many Subscribers. When viewing a subscriber in the django admin, it correctly shows which account the subscriber is related to. However, when looking at the account, it does not show which subscribers it has.

I saw an article ([How to create many-to-one relation with django and to display it in admin interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8546781/how-to-create-many-to-one-relation-with-django-and-to-display-it-in-admin-interf)) that suggested using inlines, although it’s not working for me. Where am I going wrong here?

Models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class Account(AbstractUser):
    pass


class Subscriber(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    account = models.ForeignKey(
        Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    list_display = ('first_name', 'email', 'date_joined', 'verified')
```

Admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from accounts import models

# does nothing
class SubscriberInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = models.Subscriber
    extra = 1


admin.site.register(models.Account, UserAdmin)


# does noting
class AccountAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [SubscriberInline, ]
    #inlines = (SubscriberInline, )


@admin.register(models.Subscriber)
class SubscriberAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("first_name", "email",
                    "date_joined", "verified", "account")
```

Comment: Well you didn't register your `AccountAdmin` so what do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't *register* any model to your class `AccountAdmin` and hence it will not be used. If you want to use some `ModelAdmin` you need to register it. Instead of inheriting from `ModelAdmin` try inheriting from `UserAdmin` and registering that class instead:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from accounts import models

# does nothing
class SubscriberInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = models.Subscriber
    extra = 1


class AccountAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = [SubscriberInline]


admin.site.register(models.Account, AccountAdmin)


@admin.register(models.Subscriber)
class SubscriberAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("first_name", "email",
                    "date_joined", "verified", "account")
```

---

> **Note**: You should also set the attributes `form` and `add_form` in your admin class to custom forms (inheriting from `UserChangeForm` and
> `UserCreationForm` and setting the `model` in their `Meta` class)
> since you are using a custom user model.